# How to display image on full div in html css

Tags: html, css

I try to display the image on full div but it display only center of the div
 i am using the following code
my html code is

```css
.all-stores .store-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 1px solid red
    }
```

```html
<div class="white-block all-stores">
 <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <div class="store-logo">
   <a href="test">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" class="img-responsive wp-post-image">
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: You forgot a "." prior to the class name "all-stores". Also, can you provide an illustration (visual if possible) of the current case and the desired case?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should try to explain better what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:-

```css
.img{
width:100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="white-block all-stores">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <div class="store-logo">
        <a href="test">
            <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/nest-clip-art-nest.jpg" class="img">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css Style

```
img
{
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css: https://jsfiddle.net/cq8v0rjr/

It sets the inline-block elements to 100% (which will fill its parent).

```
.store-logo > a, .store-logo > a > img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```